# Rest Service opens "WCF Test Client"

Tags: vb.net, rest, wcf

I am a beginner. And I have one REST Service in Visual Studio. Sometimes when I run the Rest Service. Everything works fine and one google chrome window opens with url as localhost. But sometimes when I do the same thing, instead of google chrome one window pops up. But Why this window opens. I just want my REST Service to be up and running. Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Please rephrase your question to understand your problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which file in your project is currently selected. If you have a .svc file selected, the WCF Test Client will start. Otherwise the default will be your browser.